# Parse json array to a case class in scala using playframework with the fields in json not matching the fields in case class

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am trying to parse a simple json array to a case class using scala and play framework. Below is the code

```
package com.learning.avinash.query

import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Json, Reads, Writes, __}
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object ParseJson extends App {

  case class InfoForm(avinash: String, kranti: String, prasanth: String)

  object InfoForm {

    implicit val reads: Reads[InfoForm] = (
      (JsPath \ "username").read[String] ~
        (JsPath \ "id").read[String] ~
        (JsPath \ "full_name").read[String]
      )(InfoForm.apply _)

  }

  val json = """ {
  "data":  [
     {
      "username": "carolinabentocb",
      "id": "363753337",
      "full_name": "Carolina Bento"
    },
     {
      "username": "pereira3044",
      "id": "2141448590",
      "full_name": "Alex"
    }]
}"""

  println(Json.parse(json).as[List[InfoForm]])

}
```

But i am getting the following exception

**Exception in thread "main" play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsarray),WrappedArray())))))**

Followed the below links

[Parse JSON Array in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680206/parse-json-array-in-scala)

[Parse Json array response in scala\Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272826/parse-json-array-response-in-scala-play)

[Parse Simple Json Array in Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365763/parse-simple-json-array-in-play-framework)

These link almost helped me

[Stepping into JSON Arrays in Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960900/stepping-into-json-arrays-in-play-framework)

[How to parse json list or array in scala for play framework 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057293/how-to-parse-json-list-or-array-in-scala-for-play-framework-2-2)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I could get the result of this. I have done it like this

```
println((Json.parse(json) \"data" ).as[List[InfoForm]])
```

This gives me the result

```
List(InfoForm(carolinabentocb,363753337,Carolina Bento), InfoForm(pereira3044,2141448590,Alex))
```